# Trying to find a book series from 80s. Fantasy world, young man going magic school

Tags: story-identification, magic

Found the series at a one of those elementary school book fairs.

It was a series and i remember reading the first 2-3 books, set in a fantasy world. This kid makes a trip to a magic school mostly populated by rich kids where magic comes easy. He isn't rich and the magic doesn't come easy. There is some kind of conflict that i cannot remember.

I remember one scene in the book where the kid and a magician are on the way to the school and they have to make a circle in the forest to keep out demons. (sounds like Peter Brett right?)

I don't have much more than that. It has been a lot of years.

Comment: Was it early or late 80's?

Comment: [Barry Trotter](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Barry_Trotter)?

Comment: Some elements of your description remind me of Le Guin's "A Wizard of Earthsea," but that book was published in 1968.

Comment: Maybe one of the works listed in TvTropes' [Wizarding School](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WizardingSchool) page? Perhaps [Groosham Grange](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/GrooshamGrange) by Anthony Horowitz or [The Worst Witch series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Worst_Witch) by Jill Murphy (which feature a female protagonist)?

Comment: @JasonAzze I was thinking that one too, but the scene in the forest, in the very first book, is not about keeping demons out.. Rather, invoking one!

Comment: Hiding in a circle to keep away from demons doesn't sound very unique, neither does going to school for magically gifted children. First series that comes to mind is [The Last Herald Mage Series](http://valdemar.wikia.com/wiki/The_Last_Herald-Mage_series) by Mercedes Lackey. Vanyel is from a rich family, but he is basically bereft of magical or social abilities, so he doesn't fit in with the other 'elite' kids for quite awhile.

Answer (score 4):

It does not match on the "protective circle of magic" point, at least in the first two books, but the *[The Circle of Magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_Magic_%28Doyle_and_Macdonald_novels%29)* series (*Wizard's Apprentice* in the UK) features Randal, a former squire, who attends a school for magicians. One of the conflicts in the first book is that magic doesn't come easily to him (he has a lot of power, but not much fine control, so he winds up doing things "the hard way"). He's on scholarship, while many of the students are rich and being paid for, so he risks getting kicked out if he doesn't find a way to learn more readily.

The main conflict in the first two books do involve demons, but they're respectively at the school and in a wizard's tower, so it doesn't quite match up for the circle in the woods. In the third book, he does create a magic circle that hides him and his companions from pursuing soldiers (but not to a ghost who shows up to give advice) but at this point in the narrative, he *is* the wizard with his travelling companion being the same age and having no magic talent.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly this question refers to the [*Majyk* series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?6276) by Esther Friesner, starting with [*Majyk By Accident*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2025402.Majyk_By_Accident) (1993). Magic is stockpiled by the mighty and only the most privileged students receive small bits of it to further their progress.